# Javascript for fading an image on-scroll is still showing the image on page load

Tags: javascript

I've got an image in a fixed-position div. The following code is fading the image in where I want to, but initially the image is visible. Once I start scrolling, it disappears and then reappears when it should. Trying to figure out why the image is displaying on page load.

```
    const checkpoint = 500;

    window.addEventListener("scroll", () => {
      const currentScroll = window.pageYOffset;
      if (currentScroll <= checkpoint) {
        opacity = 0 - currentScroll / checkpoint;
      } else {
        opacity = 1;
      }
      document.querySelector(".sticky-logo-fade-in").style.opacity = opacity;
    });
```

Comment: add a class or a `style` attribute to it with `opacity:0`

Comment: I tried that, but it never appears again, despite scrolling down the page.

Answer (score 0):

You can store the callback in a variable, then call it on page load:

```js
const checkpoint = 500;

const scrollHandler = () => {
    const currentScroll = window.pageYOffset;
    if (currentScroll <= checkpoint) {
        opacity = 0 - currentScroll / checkpoint;
    } else {
        opacity = 1;
    }
    document.querySelector(".sticky-logo-fade-in").style.opacity = opacity;
}

window.addEventListener("scroll", scrollHandler);

scrollHandler();
```

Comment: Thanks! However, the image still appears on page load.

Comment: @BillHorvath Can you provide the HTML?

Comment: The HTML is generated by the Wordpress theme, so it's too convoluted to share. However, the logo is within three divs. The outer-most div is position:fixed and I'm pretty sure that's what's causing the issue.